# Mapping array to new array

Tags: php, arrays, mapping

I have an array which has an array within it, and I want to create a new array for each of the array values of 'power'. What is the best way to do this?

Original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [stid] => 64
            [beam] => 1
            [power] => {1,3,7,8,9}
            [gates] => 5
)

   [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:17:03
            [stid] => 64
            [beam] => 1
            [power] => {14,15,16}
            [gates] => 3
)
)
```

Edit: Output array should increment gate started from 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 1
            [power] => 1
        )

   [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 2
            [power] => 3
         )

   [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 3
            [power] => 7
         )

   [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 4
            [power] => 8
         )


   [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 5
            [power] => 9
         )

   [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:17:03
            [gate] => 1
            [power] => 14
         )

   [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:17:03
            [gate] => 2
            [power] => 15
         )

   [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:17:03
            [gate] => 3
            [power] => 16
         )
)
```

Continued for all 8 (5 and 3) power values, such that the resultant array is an array of 8 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Original Data Structure
$arr = 
[
    [
        'date' => '2019-09-16 15:16:03',
        'stid' => 64,
        'beam' => 1,
        'power' => '{1,3,7,8,9}',
        'gates' => 5
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2019-09-16 15:17:03',
        'stid' => 64,
        'beam' => 1,
        'power' => '{14,15,16}',
        'gates' => 3
    ]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($arr as $a)
{
    $gateCount = 0;
    foreach (explode(',', trim($a['power'], '{}')) as $p) 
    {
        $output[] = [
            'date' => $a['date'],
            'gate' => $gateCount++ % $a['gates'] + 1,
            'power' => $p
        ];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 1
            [power] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 2
            [power] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 3
            [power] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 4
            [power] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:16:03
            [gate] => 5
            [power] => 9
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:17:03
            [gate] => 1
            [power] => 14
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:17:03
            [gate] => 2
            [power] => 15
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-09-16 15:17:03
            [gate] => 3
            [power] => 16
        )

)
```

**Note:**

`['beam']` and `['stid']` have been left off  as per your sample. Can easily be added if you need them.

Comment: This is true. In my sample recreation of the data structure, I simply made it an array,

Comment: I modified my answer to have the structure use the `{x,y}` format and the `foreach` accordingly.

Comment: Also, gate should equal 0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2 in this example. How would I make that addition?

Comment: @mcook16, edit your original question to specify how the gate index should be populated.

Comment: @mcook16 How do you want your `'gate'` defined?

Comment: @dazed-and-confused I have updated the original question. Thanks.

Comment: @mcook16 I made the change to increment `['gate']` are per your request.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused so sorry, I actually need the gate to reset for each array. Please see the updated original question.

Comment: So the gate can only be 1-5? And continuously cycles regardless of how many total arrays there are?

Comment: It will need to increment as many times as the gate value holds in each array. So 1-5 for the first array and 1-3 for the second. I updated the original to show.

Comment: Oh so the gate coincides with the number of values in power? Let's say p=power and g=gate. [p1 g1] [p3 g2] [p7 g3] [p8 g4] [p9 g5] [p14 g1] [p15 g2] [p16 g3]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: It's all set for you.

Comment: @mcook16 Glad I could help. Good luck with your project

Comment: @dazed-and-confused can you explain how this line works, and what '%' is doing here?

'gate' => $gateCount++ % $a['gates'] + 1

Comment: `%` is the [modulus operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) which returns the remainder of `$a / $b`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($oldArray as $element) {
   foreach ($element['power'] as $power) {
      $element['power'] = $power;
      $newArray[] = $element;
   }
}
```